# What XML APIs in C?

Tags: c, xml, api

Are they all this complex? : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766497(VS.85).aspx

Just need something basic to produce XML in C.

Comment: Tommy, please ask a new question, rather than changing this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/). Here is an example of use:

```
#include <libxml/parser.h>

int
main(void)
{

  xmlNodePtr root, node;
  xmlDocPtr doc;
  xmlChar *xmlbuff;
  int buffersize;

  /* Create the document. */
  doc = xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST "1.0");
  root = xmlNewNode(NULL, BAD_CAST "root");

  /* Create some nodes */
  node = xmlNewChild(root, NULL, BAD_CAST "node", NULL);
  node = xmlNewChild(node, NULL, BAD_CAST "inside", NULL);
  node = xmlNewChild(root, NULL, BAD_CAST "othernode", NULL);

  /* Put content in a node: note there are special characters so 
     encoding is necessary! */
  xmlNodeSetContent(node, 
                xmlEncodeSpecialChars(doc, BAD_CAST "text con&tent and <tag>"));

  xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root);

  /* Dump the document to a buffer and print it for demonstration purposes. */
  xmlDocDumpFormatMemory(doc, &xmlbuff, &buffersize, 1);
  printf((char *) xmlbuff);

}
```

Compiled with 'gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c create-xml.c && gcc
-lxml2 -o create-xml create-xml.o', this program will display:

```
% ./create-xml   
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <node>
    <inside/>
  </node>
  <othernode>text con&amp;tent and &lt;tag&gt;</othernode>
</root>
```

For a real example, see [my implementation](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/files/traceroute-nanog-xml.c) of [RFC 5388](http://www.ietf.org/rfcs/rfc5388.txt).

Answer (score 4):

[Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/index.html) is known to be easy, give it a try

Answer (score 3):

[MiniXML](http://www.minixml.org/) might be what you're looking for, if you need something simple, easy, and C:

> [Mini-XML: Lightweight XML Library](http://www.minixml.org/)
>
> Mini-XML is a small XML library that
>   you can use to read and write XML and
>   XML-like data files in your
>   application without requiring large
>   non-standard libraries. Mini-XML only
>   requires an ANSI C compatible compiler
>   (GCC works, as do most vendors' ANSI C
>   compilers) and a 'make' program.

However, there are a [ton of them](http://www.google.com/search?q=xml%20c%20library) ranging in complexity and needs.  MiniXML is nice in that it doesn't require more than a simple Ansi C compiler.  A lot of them require other libraries, or specific compilers.

-Adam

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make XML in C is the high-quality and free genx from Tim Bray: http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2004/02/20/GenxStatus

Answer (score 1):

- [The XML C parser](http://xmlsoft.org/) of Gnome is an extensive C API for XML.
- [XML Security Library](http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/) is a nice C library on top of libxml2.

Comment: Yep, but the fact that I'm too lame to figure out how to use the links shouldn't detract from looking into both these libraries.  They're both quite good.