# C programming XML

Tags: c, xml

HI...I'm making a project and the program receives info about people, how can i save all info to XML?

Comment: XML APIs in C? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592954/xml-apis-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Here are some [LibXML examples](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html) to do this. It is really difficult to answer "How to" questions without knowing what do you already know and do?

Comment: I know how to save to a txt file

Comment: @pedro: Well, if you now how to save a plain text file, writing XML should be no problem: just add some angle brackets! This might not be the best solution though, but then it does seem to match the style of your question ;)